# interrater reliability with 12 pairs parents rating their own children in categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data, agreement-statistics

Please accept my apologies if the answer to this question already exists.

This is the first time for me to do a study investigating the interrater reliability of a questionnaire. There are 12 pairs of parents (father and mother) who need to rate their own child by answering an identical set of 40 questions. Each question the participants have to answer categorical variables "yes", "no", or "unknown".

I would like to know which methods I could use the interrater reliability between each parent and combining them to assess the IRR of each question. And how can I assess the relationship between the demographic data of the parents and their tendency of choosing yes, no or unknown.

I would be grateful if you can give me some advises as I could not find any resources that I am looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cronbach's alpha comes to mind.

Comment: I would not use Cronbach's alpha for categorical data. Use something like Fleiss' kappa to calculate the categorical agreement between each pair of parents across the 40 questions. If you want to combine them, you can then report the average (and maybe SD) of the pairs' agreement scores.